# How do I make spikes jut off an image?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How would I create the circled spikes in the picture below, I've tried editing the path with the pen tool but that just results with the spikes not being fully through glowing blue. [image]

Answer (score 1):

That kind of effect is usually done in Photoshop but i would give this a try:

Use the Gradient Mesh tool in Illustrator. You create a shape and then add rows and columns of anchor points with the Gradient Mesh tool. You then apply each anchor point with a different color depending on what you want.

Check out the adobe help file [Illustrator Help /   Meshes](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/meshes.html)

You could also do this using the blend tool.